# How to swap elements when dragging and dropping with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I am tryig to build a small language quiz with Javascript and jQuery. Basically, people will finish the sentence by choosing the correct answers.

The sentences will be shown with missing parts that will be shuffled and displayed below. The player will drag the appropiote word or phrase into the box.

Some parts of the quiz work well but I have two following problems:

1. It is possible to add two answers to one box. It would be better that when somebody adds the second answer the first answer goes back to the div at the bottom.
2. It is possible to drop one answer into the other so then link together. After, it is possible to drag them together which looks weird.

I would really appreciate your help as this drives me crazy.

```
        <style>
             .droptarget, base {
              border: 1px dotted #aaaaaa;
              display: inline-block;
              background-color: #eee;
              min-width: 10%; height: 20px;}

              span {display:inline-block;
              margin: 0 30px 0 10px;
              white-space:nowrap;}

             .base {min-width: 30%; height: 20px;}
        </style>


            Grass is <div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" 
            ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> <span class="answer">green</span> 
            </div><br>

            Sky is <div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" 
            ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> <span class="answer">blue</span> 
            </div><br> 

            Strawberries are <div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" 
            ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> <span class="answer">red</span> 
            </div><br>

            <p id="demo"></p>

            <div id="base" class="droptarget base" ondrop="drop(event)" 
            ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

    <script>
        function dragStart(event) {
          event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
        }

        function dragging(event) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element is being dragged ";
        }

        function allowDrop(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }

        function drop(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

          if (event.target.className == 'droptarget base') {
            // alert('adding to base');
            $('.base').append(document.getElementById(data));
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element was dropped";
          } else if (event.target.innerText == "") {
            //alert('adding to empty');
            event.target.append(document.getElementById(data));
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element was dropped";
          } else {
            //alert('adding two together')
            event.target.append(document.getElementById(data));
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element was dropped";
          }
        }

        $(function() {
          $('.answer').remove();
        });

        var array = $('.answer').map(function() {
          return $.trim($(this).text());
        }).get();

        var new_array = array;
        new_array.sort(function() {
          return 0.5 - Math.random()
        });

        $.each(new_array, function(index, value) {
          $(".base").append('<span  id="' + index + '"ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondrag = "dragging(event)" onDrop = "false" ondrop = "false" draggable = "true" > ' + value + '</span>');
        });
</script>
```

My JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pawcioojf/3hzsdq76/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you add the ability to add two answers to one box if you don't want that? Just change the logic in the "else" where you add two together

Comment: I would building an object tree with this, and then after an element release, check if there is any more elements on it, if so, get element that id is not the same as the other ones, and swap it around. Just play with it.